# Creating a quadratic equation from a condition

Tags: quadratics, quadratic-forms

how can I create an equation that satisfies the following: "x-intercepts 1 and -1, y-intercept 3". I understand that the factored form of a quadratic equation offers both x intercepts however, I'm not sure of a form that offers both x intercepts and y intercepts. Here's another one: x-intercept 3, and passing through the point (1, -2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have that the x intercepts are at $-1$ and $1$, you must have a quadratic of the form $y=a(x-1)(x+1)$. Now, when $x=0$, $3=(-1)(1)a$,  so your quadratic is $y=-3(x+1)(x-1)$. 
 
For your second one; it must be of the form $y=a(x-3)^2$. Plugging in $(1,-2)$ gives $-2=a(4)$ so $y=\frac{-1}{2}(x-3)^2$.

Comment: How did you get -3? What does "a" stand for?

Comment: The most general form of a quadratic equation is $y=a(x-b)(x-c)$. Here, b and c are the x intercepts, a acts as a vertical ‘stretching’ constant. This allows you to manipulate the y intercept by changing how ‘high’ your function reaches. To get $a=-3$ substitute in $x=0$ and $y=3$ (since a y-intercept of 3 has coordinates $(0,3)$. Your b and c are given in the question as $1$ and $-1$, so substitute those in as well. Then solve for a.